# Обнуляются файлы на хостинге

Tags: php, nginx

Доброе время суток.
Возникла такая проблема. У меня на хостинге периодически рандомно обнуляются файлы, т.е. их вес становится 0 байт.

Независимо какое у них расширение и какой движок стоит. т.е. может обнулится даже если на сайте лежит один php файл с echo "Hello World!"

ОС Дебиан 8, связка nginx+php-fpm, open_basedir настроен корректно, доступ к фтп и ссш запрещены по айпи.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: свободного места на диске хватает?

Comment: Сислог, dmesg?.

Comment: Да, айнодов тоже с запасом

Comment: в логах ничего необычного

Comment: Жесткий диск битый возможно

Comment: ссд сравнительно новый